# cannot run linked server query with sa account but can run with windows authentication user

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have created a linked server(for excel) and when I run the query like below

It works when I connect SQL Server Management Studio with windows authentication and run the below query.

```
select * from linkserver...sheet1$
```

The same query gets the following error if I login with sa account.

```
 The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "exportlink"
 reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
 Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
 Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider   
 "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for     linked server "linkedserver
```

Though it seems a security issue, I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, a linked server passes through the current user credentials to the linked server.

The mapping is created by [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx) and the default is mentioned in this bit

> A default mapping between all logins on the local server and remote logins on the linked server is automatically created by executing sp_addlinkedserver. The default mapping states that SQL Server uses the user credentials of the local login when connecting to the linked server on behalf of the login. This is equivalent to executing sp_addlinkedsrvlogin with @useself set to true for the linked server, without specifying a local user name. Use sp_addlinkedsrvlogin only to change the default mapping or to add new mappings for specific local logins.

When you use "sa" then it (I'm not sure and can't test) use the SQL Server service account. You should permission this.

If it doesn't use the SQL Server service account, you need to set up a mapping for "sa":

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
        'linkserver', 'FALSE', 'sa', 'Domain\SomeUser', 'Somepassword';
```

Comment: I get error the function has too many arguments. But I have added "'" at the end of your code. Otherwise it shows incorrect syntax.
Also, note 'domain\someuser' i replaced with my computer\username

Comment: Thanks. Your command executed successfully but still gets the same error.

Comment: @user1449596: use sysinternals Process Monitor then to see if the file is actually being accessed http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645. Or check windows security logs

Comment: i'm looking into ur link...but I want to inform you in fact now it shows error "invalid account name and passwor" ...then the error continues...

Comment: i don't know which file to check